# On Click toggle menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I know there's lots of tutorials and questions about this topic, but I followed lots of them and none of them solved my problem.

The thing is: I have an HTML and CSS menu, and it's submenus are hidden. They appear when mouse hover it. I want to make the submenu appear when clicked, not when hovered.

Here's my code.

```
<ul class="gn-menu">
<li class="gn-search-item">
<input placeholder="Search" type="search" class="gn-search">
<a class="gn-icon gn-icon-search"><span>Search</span></a>
</li>
<li class="liFirst">
<a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download" href="#">Downloads</a>
<ul class="gn-submenu">
<li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-illustrator">Vector Illustrations</a></li>
<li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-photoshop">Photoshop files</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here's my css

```
    .liFirst:active .gn-submenu li, .liFirst:hover .gn-submenu li {
    display: block;
}

.gn-submenu li {
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
        transition: height 0.3s;    
        padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Can someone help me out? I know that I need some JS in order to make it works, but I don't know much about CSS...

Sorry about my bad english.
Thank you in forward.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use anchor to define when your div is focused

```
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">menu 2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu 2.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu 2.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">menu 3.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu 3.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menu 3.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

                    <style>
        ul, li{
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        nav>ul>li{
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        nav>ul ul{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
        }
        nav>ul li:active ul{
            display: block;
        }
        nav>ul ul>li{
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
        }
                    </style>
```

jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/4tYWX/2/

Comment: It close if I stop clicking the link

Comment: Sorry I thought it would work, it mean you can't maintain active state, you'll probably have to use some javascript

Answer (score 1):

Change `.liFirst:hover` to `.liFirst:active`

Comment: @BOMEz Show me where did you find this?

Comment: @SergioMorganti I just posted some of your code in a JSfiddle and it looks like there are still some CSS styles missing? Possibly some javascript too? Can you post your code to a Fiddle like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/rLRBY/

Comment: Here's the JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sermorg/wgF7h/ I don't have any JS yet to do so. Do I need JS? Oh, and seems like the menu isn't showing up on JS Fiddle. :/